# API with React.js

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, rest

Newbie to React here having a few questions.

I developed and iOS App and created a REST API with Node.js previously.

Trying to get into React I saw this thing called `create-react-app`. When I played around with it for a while it seems each react app creates its own nodejs backend of some sort.

Ie, I have to run a node server to run my react app.

But my REST API is a different project/server and I was hoping to serve static content as React.

My question is, does React + REST API require me to use two different node servers? Seems costly and painful to deploy.

Comment: `create-react-app` comes with a *dev server*, it compiles and serves your app's files on the fly. In production, you would first *build* your app which produces static files. Those are the files you serve to the client (`create-react-app` doesn't have a production server). Also, it's fairly easy to embed an express app as a sub-path of a larger app.

Comment: @Sidney, so I serve these static files something like `res.sendFile(index.html)` in my REST API server?

Comment: Basically, yes. You could make the API available under `/api`, but that's up to you. Express can be configured to directly serve static files so that you don't need to handle each file individually, more info: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: @Sidney, it seems inconvenient having to do a `yarn build` each time I want to test out the app then. Is there a way to connect the REST API with the react frontend without having to do a production build each time?

Comment: You should be able to have the app connect to the the API server, even if the app is in development (eg, being served by `create-react-app`). That allows you to make quick changes to the app while still using the main API. You might also have a development version of the API so that you aren't messing with production data (if applicable).